# Nginx reverse proxy on AWS Beanstalk and Cacheing

Tags: nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, reverse-proxy

I have a reverse proxy set up in AWS Beanstalk. The purpose is for nginx to fetch a value from the upstream Location header and store the result with the cache key of the original request URI so that future clients don't need to follow the redirect too.

Disk space gets up to 68G here: /var/nginx/cache and 30G here: /var/nginx/temp-cache. So, my proxy server's disk space fills up pretty fast.

Anyone know how I can reduce or limit the size of my cache? Or if there is a more efficient better way of doing this so my disk doesn't fill up so fast? Thanks.

```
    worker_processes  1;
user       nginx;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  65535;
}

worker_rlimit_nofile 30000;

http {
    proxy_cache_path /var/nginx/cache keys_zone=rev-origin:100m levels=1:2 inactive=7d max_size=80g;
    proxy_temp_path /var/nginx/temp-cache;

server {
    listen      80 default_server;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 500M;
    gzip on;
    location / {
      proxy_pass https://123456abc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/AB/;
      proxy_ssl_server_name on;
      proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
      proxy_cache       rev-origin;
      proxy_cache_key   $uri;
      proxy_cache_valid 200 206 1d;
      proxy_intercept_errors on;
      recursive_error_pages on;
      error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirects;
    }

    location @handle_redirects {
      resolver 8.8.8.8;

      set $original_uri $uri;
      set $orig_loc $upstream_http_location;

      # nginx goes to fetch the value from the upstream Location header
      proxy_pass $orig_loc;
      proxy_cache       rev-origin;
      proxy_intercept_errors on;
      error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirect;
      # But we store the result with the cache key of the original request URI
      # so that future clients don't need to follow the redirect too
      proxy_cache_key $original_uri;
      proxy_cache_valid 200 206 3000h;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by testing a few modules over the past few weeks. What seems to work and reduce the size of the cache is to use these modules:

```
  proxy_max_temp_file_size 1024m;
  proxy_buffer_size 4k;
  proxy_buffers 4 32k;
  proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
  proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
```